# A good and complete tutorial about reflection in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection

the question almost says it all. I think all of you know about the **visual studio designer**, and how it can show any property of an object, regardless of its type, provided that the property is allowed to be shown in the designer.

I am working on a function that could achieve the same thing, but for this, I need a **complete tutorial** about **reflection**, so that this function can treat every type of property.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a complete tutorial. The documentation is your best bet.

Comment: to be honest, the designer probably isn't using reflection - it is probably using TypeDescriptor, and abstraction *above* reflection, that can also represent other models

Comment: Ok, I shall take a look at the TypeDescriptor then

Comment: Google has the best tutorials :)

Answer (score 13):

Here are some good links :

- http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/introduction/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial
- http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/reflection/article.php/c4257
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-G7fobbBP0

Answer (score 10):

Here some info:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET
- CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter has a good chapter on Reflection

However, I'd recommend a bit different although harder approach. If you really want to completely understand the topic, that's what you need.

Read [Standard ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) Partition II: Metadata Definition and Semantics which explains how .NET uses its metadata

Then read and understand some code that reads this metadata.  Mono.Cecil would be a good candidate.

That will completely cover the Reflection topic

Comment: While there is some use in reading the standard, I find it quite hard to read. I really can recommend the linked Article on CodeProject to start with..