# Dynamically create instance of class which can be different each time and still be able to access it's properties

Tags: c#, windows-services, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have for example 3 custom classes named `class`, `test` and `unknown` as followed:

```
public class class
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public Guid ID { get; set; }
  public int interval { get; set; }
}

public class test
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public Guid ID { get; set; }
  public int interval { get; set; }
}

public class unknown
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public Guid ID { get; set; }
  public int interval { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my program i read an XML file which contains lines with the name of the class it has to create an instance of.

```
<Messages>
  <Message Name='ClassMessage' Type='class' />
  <Message Name='TestMessage' Type='test' />
  <Message Name='UnknownMessage' Type='unknown' />
</Messages>
```

I will loop through each line in the XML and based on the given type in the XML i have to create an instance of that class. I know you can achieve this with `Activator.CreateInstance()` only problem is, that i won't be able to access it's properties (name, ID, interval).

In the above example it's about only 3 classes although i'm working on something that talks against the webservice of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 and that has alot more classes which it should be able to choose from.

Comment: Do all of the classes have the same members? Why not give them all a common ancestor?

Comment: @Steve: No they don't I just created these classes in the example as easy as possible although the classes of CRM 4.0 are all completely different with different members.

Comment: I would think you could definitely do this using reflection, but it's not something I've worked with very much. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9458673/425871 which has some information on the topic.

Comment: @Steve Thanks. I will have a look at that.

Comment: Seems like naming a class 'class' is going to cause problems all by itself.

Comment: @MeredithPoor This was just an example in the program itself there are no classes named `class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object foo = Activator.CreateInstance("test");
(foo as test).name = "TestMessage";
```

Update: This is what you really want to do. [Set object property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/net-reflection-set-object-property)

Comment: This would work if i knew what class it was although at the point of creating the instance with Activator i only have a string name of the class. Therefor doing (foo as test) won't be possible cause at that point i don't know its the class test yet.

Comment: I was trying to draw that information out of you. You didn't give the context of where the activation would be happening. :-)