# C# Determine the type of a generic list

Tags: c#, list, reflection

I have a C# method that I need to pass various lists into. The type of lists will be different very often. The method itself is in a different dll and cannot know the class objects contained in the lists (no references, no using statements). The method needs to read each of the members of each of the items in a list and build and return a string based off of that.

My question is how can get the metadata for for these various objects at compiletime / runtime? Will reflection do that?

Also, once I get the metadata, how do i use it to actually use the variables?

Thank you

EDIT: currently I am using it like the following:

```
public string GetData(List<User> list){
//...
    List<RowData> rows = new List<RowData>();
    foreach (User item in list)
    {
        RowData row = new RowData();
        row.id = count++;
        row.cell = new string[3];
        row.cell[0] = item.ID.ToString();
        row.cell[1] = item.name;
        row.cell[2] = item.age.ToString();

        rows.Add(row);
     }
//...
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rows.ToArray());
```

Right now this is very specific. I want to replace this with generics so I can pass items other than "User"

Comment: Reflection is what you want, yes. See this answer for some good introductary links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428779/a-good-and-complete-tutorial-about-reflection-in-net

Comment: Perhaps consider using `dynamic` as well to avoid jumping through hoops with reflection directly.

Comment: I have updated the question with specifics about usage

Comment: @Mike check my answer again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.GetType()` will get you a `Type` and you can get a lot of descriptions about the type.

You can also discover members of the instances you have using reflection

Please be precise with what you want more exactly ?

EDIT : Here is a way, try making it an extenstion method it would be better

```
public static List<RowData> ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    List<RowData> rows = new List<JQGridRow>();


    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        RowData row = new RowData();
        row.cells = new string[properties.Length];
        int i=0;
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {  
             row.cells[i] = prop.GetValue(item, null);i++;
        }
       rows.Add(row);
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked (with a few minor syntax adjustments).

Answer (score 5):

If the parameter (will call it `list` for discussion's sake) coming into the method is `List<T>` then you can do the following:

```
Type type = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

If you just have a generic `T` class, then you can always just go with this:

```
Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
```

Comment: You need to be a little careful there; I could create a `class Foo : List<User>`, and pass a `Foo` into that method - it would work, but the `GetGenericArguments()` call would fail

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use reflection to obtain the type of an object at runtime.

Simple call to `object.GetType()` will give you the type of this instance.

What you do with this information is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
    public string GetData<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, RowData> fillRow)
    {
        List<RowData> rows = new List<JQGridRow>();
        foreach (User item in list)
        {
            RowData row = new RowData();
            row.id = count++;

            fillRow(row);

            rows.Add(row);
        }
        //...
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rows.ToArray());
    }
```

And use it like

```
        string s = GetData(users, row =>
        {
            row.cell = new string[3];
            row.cell[0] = item.ID.ToString();
            row.cell[1] = item.name;
            row.cell[2] = item.age.ToString();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work if you treat them all as objects, using the intrinsic `ToString()` method for your string building.